# MLP Classifier in Python

Tags: pandas, deep-learning, multi-layer

I am new to machine learning and I have been trying to implement a neural network in Python using Keras library. I want to implement a MLP classifier for a multi-classification problem with input dimension of [34310,33] with the output dimension as [34310,66] formed using one hot label.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENxVN.png)

I have included the architecture of the MLP classifier above in the link. I have tried to create the same in the python and I have pasted the lines below.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim = 33, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(66, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Could you please provide some validation for the above lines of code?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by saying your 66 output neurons were formed using one hot label?

Comment: Actually, there are a total of 66 classes which I represented in one hot label form for each sample